# spatie/laravel-medialibrary replace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model with Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model

Tags: laravel, mongodb, media-library

I'm using the package spatie/laravel-medialibrary and I want use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model instead of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model without editing the package src file.

```
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media as BaseMedia;
    
    class Media extends BaseMedia
    {
      
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/advanced-usage/using-your-own-model.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222613/how-to-use-jenssegers-mongodb-eloquent-model-instead-of-illuminate-database-eloq answer your question?